# Display Fetch data from table in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have problem with display data fetch from table as I would like the data auto fill in form page

I tried to link the page but as for page display already fetched the data while another insert data in form to commit in table. I would like some guidance as suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are saying, but - let me try to guess.

(BTW, is your background Oracle Forms?)

The simplest way to work with a form is to use the Wizard to create combination of

- Interactive Report (IR) which displays data already stored in a table and
- Form which is used to

  - insert new rows (that's *triggered* by pressing the "Create" button in IR)
  - update (delete included) existing values (that's triggered by pressing the *pencil* button located in the 1st column of the IR)

When you want to update existing values, Apex will use a **link** from IR's row and pass primary key value(s) to a Form. Form's pre-rendering process then fetches data related to that primary key and displays values in its items. Once you edit values and press the Apply Changes button, an automatic row processing process writes changes into the database and branch returns you to the Interactive Report page.

---

If you want to do it manually, you'll still have to pass the primary key to a form because - how will it know which row to retrieve? That's why I asked whether you used Oracle Forms before, because that tool lets you **execute query** to retrieve row(s) from the database. But, this is Apex, a whole new & different tool.